# IdHTTP Increase download speed using ranges

Tags: delphi, indy10, idhttp

I have a program that downloads files and realized that by downloading using the program the speed hangs at 300kbps, however downloading the same file using a browser doubles the speed. I have seen in some posts about using ranges to separate the file into parts and download using threads, but I could not implement it.
My code:

```
IdHTTP1.Head(URL);
Range: = IdHTTP1.Request.Ranges.Add;
Range.StartPos: = 0;
Range.EndPos: = Trunc(IdHTTP1.Response.ContentLength / 2);
IdHTTP1.Post(URL, Parameters, FS);
```

When I run the code, it returns me the whole file, i'm not sure if this code is correct, I tried to do something simple to test, but it did not work.

When I use `IdHttp.Head()` the raw header returns this information:

```
Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 18:02:11 GMT
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age = 0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "pecas.pdf"
Content-Type: application / pdf
Content-Length: 18507774
```

Comment: "*When I run the code, it returns me the whole file*" - that is because the URL you are requesting does not support ranges, as evident by the lack of an `Accept-Ranges` header in the `HEAD` response. Also, you generally can't use `HEAD` with URLs that you send `POST` to, only URLs you send `GET` to. By definition, "*The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the help, is there any other way to speed up downloading the file?